# Webots - MoveIt! Controlling two UR5e Robots

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, universal-robot, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to contrloll two ur5e arms with Moveit over Webots. My goal is to give them an endeffector pose and they go to that position. It works for one! My problem is to controll more than one. I want to have one launch file which starts a move_group node and a webots node for each robot im adding. I tried to follow the Gazebo tutorial and i wanted to use the "" command but then move_group wouldnt subscribe to my webots_joint-publisher.
I think its because my Webots  node isnt in the same namespace but i couldnt figure out how to change the namespace in my webots-python script.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345150/webots---moveit!-controlling-two-ur5e-robots/) by [Tim97_KIT](https://answers.ros.org/users/52038/tim97_kit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-27**:
Seeing as Webots is not a very commonly used simulator with ROS, I would expect you'll have a higher chance of getting a response if you'd use a more appropriate venue, such as the Webots support forum or their issue tracker.

**Comment by [Tim97_KIT](https://answers.ros.org/users/52038/tim97_kit/) on 2020-02-28**:
Thanks for your answer!
My first attempt was to ask the webots forum but they couldnt help with the problem. Thats why im here. I hoped that someone tried to use Webots with moveIt and knows how to controll multiple robots with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am not very familiar with the group command, but about Webots you should define a different 'prefix' param for each of your UR5e robot from the launch file.

For more information here is the Webots controller that provide the ROS interface for the UR5e robot: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/tree/master/projects/robots/universal_robots/controllers/universal_robots_ros

---

Originally posted by [DavidMansolino](https://answers.ros.org/users/40575/davidmansolino/) with karma: 46 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim97_KIT](https://answers.ros.org/users/52038/tim97_kit/) on 2020-03-02**:
Hi,
So i have to use two launchfiles for each robot and change the prefix from each one?
I tried it for one robot and then it cant find the joints anymore.

**Comment by [DavidMansolino](https://answers.ros.org/users/40575/davidmansolino/) on 2020-03-03**:
To simplify the process, a new argument called `--node-name` have been introduced in https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pull/1423.
With this patch you can now directly set in the Webots scene-tree in the `controllerArgs` fields the name of the node to avoid name clash when using more than one robot with ROS.